# sqoop importing string column of a dataset containing "," in it

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

the Dataset I am importing contains string columns with "," in them.
When I try to import , the string value is getting split into fields.

Here is my sqoop script:

`sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://XXX.XX.XX.XX:51260;database=Common' -username=BIG_DATA  -P --table Carriers   --hive-import --hive-table common.Carriers --hive-drop-import-delims --optionally-enclosed-by '\"' --map-column-hive UpdatedDate=string,ResourceID=string --lines-terminated-by '\n' -- --schema Truck -m 10`

the sqoop command works fine for integer type columns but it splits the string columns as they contain ","(camma) within the string . so is there any way to escape it while parsing the string containing  ","

Comment: can you show me your sample input and sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding this **--fields-terminated-by '^'** to sqoop import solved similar problem of mine

Comment: but I need fields separated by ',' for querying. So cant use fields separated by '^'

Comment: while querying even if the field separator is ^, your queries will work fine.

Comment: but i am unable to query it with presto when using '^' as field sepreator

Answer (score 0):

This should work

$ sqoop import --fields-terminated-by , --escaped-by \ --enclosed-by '\"' ...